# How to make custom rectangle shape with hex color of any color with opacity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-drawable, opacity, android-shape

Is there any possibility to draw a rectangle shape with any hex color with opacity for that color

for example blue_color_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid
        android:color="#29618E"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="@dimen/_10sdp"/>

</shape>
```

The above code is a normal rectangle shape with a radius of 10dp

But I want the given opacity for the shape without changing the hex code. And how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change a color, you can add `android:alpha` property to your View. For example:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_color_backgroung"
    android:alpha="0.5"/>
```

Comment: I just use the above **blue_color_background.xml** as background of the view. And this is not the exact answer I am looking for. Thanks for commenting

Comment: @SumanRadhakrishnan do you have a picture of what are you looking for ?

Comment: @LouisChabert [https://prnt.sc/20z0j12] this is example image

Answer (score 0):

The opacity attribute in android XML is **alpha** you can set alpha for a view in the range of 0.0 to 1.0 which 0.0 is fully transparent.
just use like this :

```
android.alpha="0.7"
```

Comment: setting alpha to parent view also affect the child view. Not the exact answer I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
Drawable customeShape = 
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_shape);

 // setting the opacity (alpha)

customeShape.setAlpha(10);

// setting the images on the ImageViews

image.setImageDrawable(customeShape);
```

Comment: for your kind information **getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_shape)** is deprecated.